# Rails 5 - Validate devise users email based on scope of two dynamic attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

How can I validate a users email based on some condition thereby overriding devise default [VALIDATABLE](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/main/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb) feature.

Users table has company_id(has one role as owner) and institution_id(has two roles as tutor and student) with belongs_to :role model

So how can I achieve the following scenarios -

1. A user with email **a@gmail.com** must be allowed to register if he is the **owner**(role) of the **Company** name Apple.
2. A user with email **a@gmail.com** must also be allowed to register if he is a **tutor** in an **Institution** named Apple-1 belonging to the **Company** Apple.
3. A user with email **a@gmail.com** must also be allowed to register if he is a **student** in an **institution** named Apple-1 belonging to the **company** Apple.

How can I check the uniqueness of the email and scope it based on above conditions.
I dont want to mess up with the Default Validatable module of devise neither want to update my authentication keys in devise.rb apart from email and username.

Can i acheive this conditionally as everytime i see email is checked for uniqueness irrespective of my code added in `user.rb`, so everytime email registration fails as its always been found without any scope added.

```
in user.rb
##it runs but of no use as default email check is also ran by default.
  validates :institution_id, uniqueness: {
    scope: [ :company_id, :email ],
    message: "Email exists for the institution"
  }
```

Comment: This is way beyond the scope of what the uniqueness validation is supposed to handle. It's just a simple wrapper around a database query which checks if any records exist that match the combination of the column plus all the scopes.  You need a [custom validation method](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations) or some other solution like a [Pundit policy](https://github.com/varvet/pundit).

Comment: I am confused here. Can **a@gmail.com** register 3 times? Either way I agree with @max that this validation should be handled separately due to the multi-branch complexity outlined in the question.

Comment: Yes @engineersmnky, as he can be an owner, a tutor and also a student, so three different variations can exists of the same person